# UIActivityView Button Error

Tags: swift, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to use UIActivityView to create a sharing button for my app. When I press the button in the app I get an error. What's wrong with the code?

```
@IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let texttoshare = "Sharing"
        let URLtoshare = NSURL(string: "www.google.com")
        let objectsToShare:NSArray = [texttoshare, URLtoshare!]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare as! [Any], applicationActivities: nil)

        self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
    }
```

The error: is Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: Please add the error to your question.

Comment: try changing `NSURL(string: ...`  to `URL(string: ...` and remove the `:NSArray`

Comment: @LucianoRodríguez still the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. At least, it's working for me without errores..

```
let texttoshare = "Sharing"
let URLtoshare = URL(string: "www.google.com")
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [texttoshare, URLtoshare!], applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you want to use `UIActivityViewController` for iPads, you need to specify `popoverPresentationController?.sourceView` for `activityVC`. For example:

```
let texttoshare = "Sharing"
let URLtoshare = URL(string: "www.google.com")
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [texttoshare, URLtoshare!], applicationActivities: nil)
activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = button...
self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: what do you put for "button..."? I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: anything you want... For example the shareButton IBOutlet... or self.view if you prefer. Test a couple of views and see what fits your needs...